# Efficiently displaying a really long string in UITextView?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a really long NSString and I like to display it in a UITextView. The problem is it is eating up RAM and CPU. I thought about displaying the string character for character, but I dont know how to do this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is "really long" in this case? What part of the code does instruments tell you consume the most CPU? How much memory is being allocated and how/where?

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Well, I cant tell you exactly how long the string is, but I want to show the bytes of a file in a UITextView (so making a NSString out of NSData of the file). If the file is 119kb big the CPU goes up to 100% and RAM is at 60MB.

Comment: eg. one string has 276212 signs.